# Fetch with SQL query works if query contains "LIMIT x", but not if fetch call contains url + "?limit=x"

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, fetch-api

I have a web app hosted within Google Cloud, written in JavaScript. I'm using the fetch function to get data from a sql database also hosted within Google Cloud. If the code where that function is called looks like this:

> const response = await fetch('/v1/replacements', {etc})

And the code where the query is held looks like this:

> const getReplacements = 'SELECT
> etc etc etc LIMIT 50'

Then it works fine. But I need that limit to work as a variable, plus I want to add an offset.

When I change those two lines to

> const response = await fetch('/v1/replacements?limit=50', {etc})'

and

> const getReplacements = 'SELECT etc etc etc' (there's no limit here this time)

Then I don't get a response from SQL.

I've also tried using

> fetch('/v1/replacements' + new URLSearchParams({limit: 50}))

to no avail.  Any ideas?

Longer versions of code:

AdminReplacements.js

```
const getReplacements = async (e) => {
  try {
    if (currentUser && !currentUser) {
      window.location = "/login";
    } else if (currentUser && currentUser.permissions !== "admin") {
      window.location = "/replacements";
    }
    const response = await fetch(`/v1/replacements`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.accessToken}`,
        Cookie: `accessToken=${currentUser.accessToken}; refreshToken=${currentUser.refreshToken};`,
      },
      credentials: "include",
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    const jsonData = await response.json();

    setReplacements(jsonData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
};
```

queries.js

```
const getReplacements = `SELECT
    l.*, o.num_leads, a.first_name, a.last_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads l WHERE l.ref_order = o.id) AS lead_count, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads l WHERE l.replacement_status = 'approved' AND l.ref_order = o.id) AS replacement_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads l WHERE l.ref_order = o.id AND l.replacement_status = 'approved') AS approved_count, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads l WHERE l.ref_order = o.id AND l.replacement_status = 'requested') AS pending_count, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads l WHERE l.ref_order = o.id AND l.replacement_status = 'rejected') AS rejected_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads l WHERE l.ref_order = o.id AND l.replacement_status IN('approved', 'requested', 'rejected')) AS replaced_count
FROM leads l 
LEFT JOIN orders o 
    ON o.id = l.ref_order 
LEFT JOIN agents a 
    ON a.id = o.ref_agent 
WHERE l.replacement_status IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY l.replacement_status = 'requested' DESC, l.created DESC
LIMIT 50`;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay, I added the full code of both sections.

Comment: So what you're really saying is that removing the `LIMIT` clause from your SQL query results in no response? This doesn't seem related at all to how you're formatting URL query parameters. Focus on the server-side issue first; check your logs, try different hard-coded limit values, etc

Comment: No, removing the limit clause works fine, except it returns thousands of results and takes like 20 minutes to load the page.

Comment: 20 mins is probably too long and the request times out. Just adding the `?limit=50` URL query parameter doesn't do anything on its own. You would need to use it in your SQL query somehow (eg `req.query.limit`). Please [edit] your question with a more comprehensive example of your server-side code... how are requests handled / routed? How is the SQL query executed?

Comment: I don't understand what "server side code" means. I'm sorry, I'm not an expert, I'm just trying to help a friend with his website. There is a .js file called "queries.js" as shown above where the sql call is spelled out completely. There is another .js file called "adminreplacements.js" as shown above that is somehow using that sql call. I don't understand what "/v1/replacements" is, I think it is a Google Cloud Project thing.